# Unable to send mail with PHP (phpmailer) via Office365 in Hostgator. How to fix this?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, office365

I want to be able to send mails in [Hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com/shared.shtml) via office365. I was able to do it with Gmail, but can not set it up to work with office365.

It works on my 2 other servers. The only problem is Hostgator.

Do I have to fix something or Hostgator have to take some action?

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);



$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = "pod51014.outlook.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "usernamehere";
$mail->Password = "************";

/* ... addaddres, reply, subject, message -> the usual stuff you need ... */

$mail->Send();

?>
```

I just keep getting following response:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
```

I was on the support chat with them and the 587 port should be open.

Comment: I think you really need to speak to their support again.

Answer (score 0):

I think hostgator is blocking outgoing emails but accepts incoming emails.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting provider doesn't allow outbound SMTP mail, I suggest you take a look at [Microsoft Graph](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message) - a REST API which let's you also send e-mails and do much more. You can use for example [oauth2-azure](https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure) library to interact with it very easily from your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things. Maybe something will work.

Set the host to:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
```

Do not set a port at all:

```
//$mail->Port = 587;
```